# Profile data using $_GET[]

Tags: php

I currently have a file using `$_GET['id'] = $userProfileNumber`, to uniquely produce appropriate user data.

My question is: In order to make sure I redirect the user to their OWN profile should I be referencing `"profile.php?=".$ownID` in all profile links? Or is there an easier way? Thank you.

`$ownID= id` from email column upon login, used to represent logged in user.

Comment: What happens if the user changed the URL and adds another ID? Can it load other people's data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would divide the answer into two major scenarios.

1. First scenario: The profile page is public. You are interested that each user would see the profile of his mate. In this case, I would totally agree with your way, as there are lots of users. Even here, on Stackoverflow, you can click on my profile below and witness the user id in the URL (with additional user name which is not required, just for prettiness' sake).
2. Second scenario: The profile page is private. It is merely intended for the use of the current logged in user. Here, I would go with the idea of Ben Fried - caching the repeated user data as a cookie or in local / session storage and pass it as a HTTP header / payload.

   **Security issues** in this approach: you should consider an authentication mechanism. I.e generating an authenticated token on log in to be stored for a later use. In each request, validate this token and only then retrieve the desired and protected data.

Comment: Yes this is along the lines of social media site, making each page public

Answer (score 2):

You could store their ID in a session upon login and have profile.php get the ID from the session rather than the URL parameter using $_GET.